# how to access <i> tag from the nested <li> which has no class name or id using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this webpage[1]. I want to access the 'Rs' column from the link using beautiful soup

my code:

```
rupees= job.ul.find('li').find('i',class_='material-icons rupee')
```

Result: none

expected: Rs 1.10 - 3.20 Lacs p.a.

[1] https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=work%20from%20home&txtLocation=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hadn't provided any other code then that just one line, but I understood what you are trying to do.

Change that single line code to this:

```
rupees= job.ul.find_all("li")[1].find(text=True,recursive=False)
```

Don't forget to mark this as accepted answer if it helps you to solve your problem.